# UTF-32 code points (surrogate pairs) in ANTLR3 lexer?

Tags: antlr, antlr3

Is there any way to specify UTF-32 code points in the ANTLR3 lexer?  More specifically I have a value like 0xAEC35 being returned from the UTF16LA (because I used a surrogate pair), but I cannot figure out how to specify this type of character (larger than 0xFFFF) in the lexer.  As is, the lexer is throwing an error because the character is not matching anything.

I'm using ANTLR 3.5.2 and the internal handling has been changed to return UTF-32 but it seems unusual the lexer doesn't seem to handle those values very well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ANTLR3 doesn't support Unicode beyond the BMP. You really should upgrade to ANTLR4, which is available since years.